# With Visual Studio 2008 how can I set what file path my published setup.exe installs to?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation, publishing

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C# desktop app that I can publish an installer for just fine, however it installs itself into the User\AppData\ folder I can't seem to figure out how to make it go some normal place like Program Files. Also, how can I make it put a folder and shortcut in the Programs list of the Start Menu?

Comment: More than 3300 rep and I'm still human? Contrary to popular belief, the amount of rep you have does not make you less tired at the end of the day. Sorry to put a ding in your perfect little world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you built a ClickOnce installer.  Try adding a Setup project to your solution.